# использование mongo в php на windows

Tags: php, windows, apache, mongodb

Не может найти класс MongoDB\Driver\Manager

```
" Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found in C:\Apache24\htdocs\mongo\mo.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Apache24\htdocs\mongo\mo.php on line 4"
```

код для подключения:

```
$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
```

я проверил в консоли, модуль mongodb встал

[image: Консоль]

менял битность модуля, качал библиотеку mongo отдельно с гитхаба

версия php 7.4 , apachi 2.4

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Где код?

перед классом добавьте

```
use MongoDB;
```